# Unit testing angular service is not calling with expected param

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am testing a `cancelWebSiteBuyRequest` function that makes a call to a put request. I have done this many times but for some reason here I keep getting the error:

> Expected spy put to have been called with 
>       [ '/:orgId/WebSites/:webSiteId/BuyRequests/:requestId/Cancel', { orgId : 19, webSiteId : 4, requestId : 5432 }, { message : 'this is my
>   campaign post' } ]
>        but actual calls were 
>       [ '/:orgId/WebSites/:webSiteId/BuyRequests/:requestId/Cancel', { orgId : 19, webSiteId : 4, requestId : 5432 }, { message : { message :
>   'this is my campaign post' } } ].

I have done this the same way many times but I cannot find what I missed that causes the passed message to be called as the full object and not just the string I am pointing it too.

Function I am testing:

```
this.cancelWebSiteBuyRequest = function (orgId, webSiteId, requestId, message) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

            apiResource.put('/:orgId/WebSites/:webSiteId/BuyRequests/:requestId/Cancel', { orgId: orgId, webSiteId: webSiteId, requestId: requestId }, { message: message })
            .then(function (data, status, headers) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }, function (data, status, headers) {
                deferred.reject("There was a problem canceling this buy request.");
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Test:

```
describe('webSiteBuyRequestService', function () {

    beforeEach(module('pb.webSites.services'));

    var mockApiResourceProvider;

    var continuationToken = {
        nextPartitionKey: 4352632,
        nextRowKey: 613
    };

    var mockAccount = {
        //entityId: 'r43',
        //accountId: 436675,
        orgId: 19,
        page: 2,
        length: 12,
        requestId: 5432,
        campaignId: 3215,
        startDate: '05/02/25',
        endDate: '06/24/15',
        filterPath: '/:account/',
        filterRegion: 'North Amarica',
        webSiteId: 4,
        message: { message: "this is my campaign post" },
        buyRequestId: 5423
    };

    beforeEach(function () {
        mockApiResourceProvider = {
            hasError: false,
            get: function (url, params) {
                return {
                    then: function (callback, errorCallback) {
                        if (!mockApiResourceProvider.hasError) return callback(mockAccount);
                        return errorCallback();
                    }
                };
            },
            post: function (url, params, data) {
                return {
                    then: function (callback, errorCallback) {
                        if (!mockApiResourceProvider.hasError) return callback(data);
                        return errorCallback();
                    }
                };
            },
            put: function (url, params, data) {
                return {
                    then: function (callback, errorCallback) {
                        if (!mockApiResourceProvider.hasError) return callback(data);
                        return errorCallback();
                    }
                };
            },
            delete: function (url, params) {
                return {
                    then: function (callback, errorCallback) {
                        if (!mockApiResourceProvider.hasError) return callback();
                        return errorCallback();
                    }
                };
            }
        };

        module(function ($provide) {
            $provide.value('apiResource', mockApiResourceProvider);
        });

        inject(function ($injector) {
            webSiteBuyRequestService = $injector.get('webSiteBuyRequestService');
        });

    });


describe('cancelWebSiteBuyRequest() function', function () {

        var baseURL = '/:orgId/WebSites/:webSiteId/BuyRequests/:requestId/Cancel';

        var baseCall = { orgId: mockAccount.orgId, webSiteId: mockAccount.webSiteId, requestId: mockAccount.requestId };

        it("with no error", function () {
            spyOn(mockApiResourceProvider, "put").and.callThrough();
            var result = webSiteBuyRequestService.cancelWebSiteBuyRequest(mockAccount.orgId, mockAccount.webSiteId, mockAccount.requestId, mockAccount.message);

            expect(mockApiResourceProvider.put).toHaveBeenCalledWith(baseURL, baseCall, mockAccount.message);

            expect(result.$$state.status).toEqual(1);
            expect(result.$$state.value).toEqual(mockAccount.message);
        });
});
```

Also if I change the code to use mockAccount.message.message it gives me the error

> Expected spy put to have been called with [ >'/:orgId/WebSites/:webSiteId/BuyRequests/:requestId/Cancel', { orgId : 19, >webSiteId : 4, requestId : 5432 }, 'this is my campaign post' ] but actual >calls were [ '/:orgId/WebSites/:webSiteId/BuyRequests/:requestId/Cancel', { >orgId : 19, webSiteId : 4, requestId : 5432 }, { message : 'this is my campaign >post' } ].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your product code is wrapping an object around the message you are sending in:

```
, { message: message }
```

You are then sending `mockAccount.message` as a parameter.  So you end up with:

```
{ message: { message: 'this is my campaign post' }};
```

I think you want to send in `mockAccount.message.message` (just the text):

```
it("with no error", function () {
    spyOn(mockApiResourceProvider, "put").and.callThrough();
    var result = webSiteBuyRequestService.cancelWebSiteBuyRequest(mockAccount.orgId, mockAccount.webSiteId, mockAccount.requestId, mockAccount.message.message);
```

Then, inside the production code, you will wrap the text and produce:

```
{ message: 'this is my campaign post' }
```

Which will then match `mockAccount.message`;

Comment: thats what I thought as well but if I change it to mockAccount.message.message I the error I just posted to the bottom of my question. Ps thanks for showing me you can format errors!

Comment: Can you show where you changed to `message.message`?